# Reuse class members in Scala

Tags: scala

I have 2 case classes in Scala, like this:

```
case class CaseClass(
                                           commonAttribute1: Int,
                                           commonAttribute2: String,
                                           commonAttribute3: String,
                                           commonAttribute4: String,
                                           commonAttribute5: String,
                                           .
                                           .
                                           .
                                         )
                                        
case class CaseClassDuplicate(
                                           commonAttribute1: Int,
                                           commonAttribute2: String,
                                           commonAttribute3: String,
                                           commonAttribute4: String,
                                           commonAttribute5: String,
                                           .
                                           .
                                           .
                                           particularAttribute1: Timestamp,
                                           particularAttribute2: Long
                                           
                                         )
```

Is there a way to create a common class so that when you declare the duplicate class to write something like this: CaseClassDuplicate(particularAttribute1: Timestamp,particularAttribute2: Long), instead of re-writing all of the members? Thanks!

Comment: Why not using composition instead? `case class CaseClassDuplicate(original: CaseClass, particularAttribute1: Timestamp, particularAttribute2: Long)`

Comment: That's a good idea, thank you! It looked more like an abstraction problem to me, so I tried so approach it like this and didn't succeed

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following two solutions:

```scala
case class CaseClassDuplicate(
                               common: CaseClass,
                               particularAttribute1: Timestamp,
                               particularAttribute2: Long)
```

or

```scala
trait AbstractCommonClass {
  val commonAttribute1: Int
  val commonAttribute2: String
  val commonAttribute3: String
  val commonAttribute4: String
  val commonAttribute5: String
}
trait AbstractPractical {
  val particularAttribute1: Timestamp
  val particularAttribute2: Long
}

case class ConcreteClass() extends AbstractCommonClass with AbstractPractical
```

And implement all variables on `ConcreteClass`.

Its all depends on your usage, share more details to get more specific answer